# how to pass value from dialog service to parent angular 2

Tags: angular, dialog, parent

I have an angular dialogservice which opens up a popup, the popup has one field whose text has to be captured once you click 'yes', how can I pass value back to parent from dialogservice

```
  this.popupservice.addDialog(Component,
                 {
                     title: 'Confirmation',
                     message: 'test'

                 })
                 .subscribe((isConfirmed) => {
                     if (isConfirmed) {
                     // catch returnText here
                         return true;
                     } else {
                         return false;
                     }
                 });

export interface CompModel {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  returnText: string;
}                
export class Component extends
  PopupComponent<CompModel, boolean>{
  implements CompModel {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  returnText: string

    confirm() {
    // send return from here
    this.close();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use EventEmitter in the service layer and receive any events from the service.

Please refer this link : 
[Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular/35568924#35568924)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value as an argument in the `close()` method and you can access this value in your `subscription`. Check the docs for this.

Comment: the dialogservice that I use doesn't accept params for close()

Comment: Which dialog service are you using??